# bash append to string via sed - but not at the end of the line

Tags: string, bash, sed, replace

I have a file called `foo.sh`

how can I edit /append the following value:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<yourProxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<yourProxyPort>
```

to the file with contents of the `AMBARI_JVM_ARGS`

```
foo
bar baz
export AMBARI_JVM_ARGS="$AMBARI_JVM_ARGS -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ROOT/etc/ambari-server/conf/krb5JAASLogin.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false"
export PATH=$PATH:$ROOT/var/lib/ambari-server
some
more things
```

so that the desired result would look like:

```
foo
bar baz
export AMBARI_JVM_ARGS="$AMBARI_JVM_ARGS -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ROOT/etc/ambari-server/conf/krb5JAASLogin.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Dhttp.proxyHost=<yourProxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<yourProxyPort>"
export PATH=$PATH:$ROOT/var/lib/ambari-server
some
more things
```

So far, I could not get it to work with sed.

Comment: Editing the source of the script seems extremely misdirected. Your script already takes any previous value of `AMBARI_JVM_ARGS` and appends some settings to that -- so just call it with `AMBARI_JVM_ARGS` set to the values you want to also include.

Comment: Good point so it might be better to set the environment variable directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already appending text to the previous value of the variable you are trying to modify. Assuming the order of the options isn't significant, simply call the script with the value already appended to the variable.

```
AMBARI_JVM_ARGS="$AMBARI_JVM_ARGS -Dhttp.proxyHost=<yourProxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<yourProxyPort>" ./foo.sh
```

(This turns out very long, so here's a shortened pseudocode version for legibility:

```
var="$var with new value appended" ./foo.sh
```

i.e. override the value of `var` with a value which includes the previous value and a suffix, and run the script with this temporary value in place for the duration of the command.  The shell command `var=value command` sets `var` to `value`, runs `command`, and restores the original value of `var`.)

Editing the source of the script seems like very poor practice. The proper solution is almost always to refactor the script to take a parameter instead. But yours already does that, so no refactoring is necessary -- just use the facility which is already there.

Answer (score 1):

You need regular expression replacement, like this:

```
sed -ri.bak 's/^(export AMBARI_JVM_ARGS=.*)"$/\1 -Dhttp.proxyHost=<yourProxyHost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<yourProxyPort>"/g' foo.sh
```

The '-r' enables regular-expression extend. '-i' means 'edit in-place' which is what you need: change the file. If the '.bak' is specified, sed creates 'foo.sh.bak' to save the file before changed, you can ignore the '.bak' (but keep '-i') then the backup file will not be created.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append at the end of the line that begins with "export", you can do:

```
sed -i -E "s/export\(.*\)$/export\1<TEXT_TO_APPEND>/" AMBARI_JVM_ARGS
```

Comment: This changes any `export` (and assumes `AMBARI_JVM_ARGS` is the name of a file, instead of the name of the variable to modify) so not really what the OP is asking.

Comment: @tripleee mmm then I'm not sure what OP is looking for.